# How to run script for specific page from child-theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a project that I have a child-theme on which I'm running specific functions from the `function.php` file.

My problem is that when I try to add an if condition to only run the script on a specific page, it doesn't work.

I'm using the **functions.php** from the child theme.

In other words... I need to be able to get the current page on the child theme.

What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action(
    'init', function() {
        if (is_page('contact')) {
            wp_register_script( 'my-func', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'my-func.js', '', '', false );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'my-func' );
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't use is_page before `posts_selection` action... so Init is to early.

Answer (score 0):

for theme code will go to your functions.php file and for plugin code will go to the public functions.

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );

 function my_assets()
 {
    if (is_page('booking')) {
        /* for plugin */
        wp_enqueue_style($this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/custom.css', array(), $this->version, 'all');
        /*for theme */
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    }
 }
```